# К — только предлог?

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Словари относят «к» исключительно к предлогу, или называя приставкой в их общем списке, или не удостаивая статьёй. Иногда в составе наречий — «слитно записанным» предлогом, и никогда не относят эту приставку к предложной. В чём причина такой предвзятости, если слов и кроме наречий с этой приставкой достаточно (крушить, клониться)?

Comment: Если в "клониться" К приставка, значит, корень тот же, что и в "льнуть"? Или нет?

Comment: Может быть тот же, что и в "лоно" ("на лоне природы").

Comment: В любом случае этот корень, каким бы ни был,  состыковывается с другими приставками.

Comment: Интересно было бы найти "лониться" с другими приставками (и без "к").  "Слоняться"?  при-с-лониться?  Тот же корень или нет?

Comment: Заслониться, прислониться, слоняться

Comment: А без "с" этот корень с приставками где-то найдётся?  А то ведь нет уверенности в том, что "с" не часть корня...

Comment: Полони́ть, заполонить.

Comment: "Полонить" имеет корень "полон"="плен", насколько мне изветстно.  Или Вы хотите сказать, что "плен" ("полон") - не корень, а приставка "по-" и корень "лон"?  А как же "пленить"?  Приставка "п-" и корень "лен" (как в слове "лениться")?

Answer (score 8):

> Словари относят «к (ко)» исключительно к предлогу...

По-моему, это не так.

В словаре Ефремовой и Кузнецовой ("Словарь морфем русского языка", М., 1986) ***"к"*** и ***"ко"*** названы префиксами (приставками).

Приставка ***"к"*** в этом словаре выделяется в следующих словах:

*к-зад-и,
к-наруж-и,
к-перед-и,
к-ста-т-и,
к-верх-у,
к-низ-у,
к-ряд-у,
к-н-утр-и,
ни-к-ч-ём-н-ый;*

приставка ***"ко"*** -- в этих:

*ко-луп-а-ть, 
ко-луп-ну-ть, 
вс-ко-луп-ну-ть,
вы-ко-луп-ыва-ть*

и др. словах с корнем *"луп"*, а также в слове

*за-ко-ул-ок.*

==========================================

"К" называется приставкой и [здесь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/277805):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Посмотрю.

Answer (score 3):

Почему? Возможно, потому, что предлог, становясь приставкой, обычно сохраняет ясный смысл. Например, предлоги "к" и "от" придают смысл, в частности, направления (приближения и удаления). Приставка "от-"может иметь такой смысл (отвязать, отцепить, отсоединить, отглагольный и т.д.). Обратный же направленческий смысл выражается не добавлением приставки "к-", а приставками "при", "под". Поэтому практически безразлично, к корню относить "к-" или называть это приставкой в случаях, когда словообразование происходило с добавлением "к". Показательно, что приставки обычно сочетаются с идентичными предлогами: "надеть на", "отцепить/отъехать от", но "подъехать/приехать к" - нет сочетаемости предлога "к" с мнимой "родной" приставкой. Даже проявление этой тенденции в выражении "клониться к" не приводит к выявлению такой приставки (там это иноземный корень). Не прижилась она как действующая сущность.

Comment: Полезно, понял.

Comment: @Alex_ander, из какого источника Вы почерпнули сведения о том, что в слове "клониться" иноземный корень? Фасмер и Шанский, например, об этом не говорят.

Comment: У Фасмера приводится древнегреческое κλίνειν.

Answer (score 1):

Слова с приставкой КО: коверкать, ковылять, ковырять, колупать, закоулок, колебать, конура.

Крушить - крошить - кроха - звукоподражательный корень kru.

Клонить - греческий корень klino - наклонять.

Comment: Эта приставка — не бедная родственница. Обидно за «к-». К — только предлог?

Comment: Рушить - рухлядь, а рухлядь - это движимое имущество (пожитки). Черных определяет формант  ru как очень плодовитый корень, связанный с движением или устремлением: бросаться, кидаться, устремляться. А приставка К не встречается, даже в паре класть - положить К относится к корню.

Comment: Обрушить — тоже от крохи или рухляди? Крошить: порошить - ворошить. Я тоже за плодовитость формант ru. Есть мнение, приставка К относится и к Клину, и к Клинку.

Comment: Но Ваши варианты очень похожи на народную этимологию: если от крушить отнять рушить, то получится приставка К. У меня к словарю Черных как-то больше доверия.