# Этимология слов "ластик" и "ластиться"

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова "ластик" и "ластиться" к этимологически однокоренным?

Comment: Как обосновать тире в  «Ластик — этимология»?

Comment: @shampar также как и тире в  "[К — только предлог?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418694/%D0%9A-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3)"

Comment: Не вижу связи. Вы скопировали картинку.

Comment: @shampar картинку?

Comment: Да. Картинка похожа, а содержание повода для тире не даёт. Надо думать...